# Comparison between two dates not showing correct result

Tags: java

In my android app, I need to find which date is greater or smaller.I have used the following code.This code works good but sometimes it shows wrong output.Pls help

```
    String strDate1 = "3/9/2013";   
    String strDate2 = "4/6/2013";   

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "m/d/yyyy" );   
    java.util.Date d1;
    java.util.Date d2;
    try {
        d1 = sdf.parse( strDate1 );
        d2 = sdf.parse( strDate2 );   
        if  ( d1.after(d2))  
        {   
              System.out.println( "d1 is after d2" ); 
        }   
        else if  ( d1.before(d2) )
        {   

           System.out.println( "d1 is before d2" ); 
        }   
        else  
        {   
           System.out.println( "d1 is equal to d2" );   
        }  

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the above code i got the output as "d1 is after d2".But the real thing is "d1 is before d2".Pls suggest if I did any mistake on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you used wrong format for month.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "M/d/yyyy" );
```

`m` is for minutes in hours
`M` is for Month in year

Answer (score 0):

try change your date format to the following

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "M/d/yyyy" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get months using `M` not minutes which is provided by `m`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "M/d/yyyy" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) this shows small m is for minute and capital M is for month so try changing it.